# How to write a toString method without using other class libraries

Tags: c#

I want to write my own toString method since I am not allowed to use any class libraries.

So I took a look into the source code of the toString method, but it uses a lot of other libraries. I want to convert an Integer into a String, but I am not sure how i can address the numbers one by one.

If I could do that, I could continue by casting the Integers into a Char and in the end add up all the Chars for a String.

Can someone help?

Comment: So what's the problem with chars?

Comment: Could you please show the input?

Comment: Share some code of what you have already tried so we can see where you are Stuck. Maybe us [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/)

Comment: *I am not sure how i can address the numbers one by one* ... me too as I have no idea what you are talking about

Comment: @MrMaavin Questions here should include the code in the question itself.

Comment: To get the digits of an integer one by one, repeatedly take the modulus of the number when divided by 10 (`number % 10`), then divide the number by 10. Repeat until the number is zero. That gives you the digits in reverse order.

Comment: Are you *sure* you need to create your own ToString method? Maybe the requirement is just "do not use *third party* libraries"

Comment: Not using the `System` library (which contains most of the basic useful stuff, including `int.ToString()`) isn't really an option since the code will implicitly reference it anyway, so it's not clear what the purpose of your constraints is. Is it a homework exercise where you're explicitly requested to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I am with Jeroen. If you are not allowed to use (any) libs, .net is not for you. Pretty much any higher language is not for you. That doesn't make sense, really.

Comment: This *must* be a homework question, surely?

Comment: Note that there's nothing *wrong* with homework questions, but it really helps to know what your problem is, because no actual .NET programmer would write code to do this independently for production purposes -- it's already there and better/faster than you could reinvent it. As a homework exercise it's not terrible because there are several subtleties that can teach you more about the language (two's complement, dynamic array allocation, the modulo operator, loops). Notably, the two answers that have been posted as of writing both contain bugs.

Comment: It is a homework question, I also marked it as a homework question in the beginning. I know its stupid, but thats what the professor wants..

Comment: I dont understand why I am getting hated so much for asking. I could not find any related question on Stackoverflow or Google. I did not ask for someone to write my code completely, I just asked for some advices

Comment: SO sees a lot of homework questions that aren't clearly presented as homework questions (as in: this is my task, it's just an exercise, this is what I already have, and here is the part I don't understand and need help with). Open-ended questions that just say "I need to do [this easy thing that the language already has with some unexplained restrictions]" attract downvotes because people will assume you're just being lazy and want a whole answer so you can copy-paste it and take undeserved credit. Don't take it personally; it might help you write a better question in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a similar approach to the other answers.

The important points:

1. We calculate the last digit of a number by finding its remainder when it's divided by 10 (i.e. `lastDigit = number % 10;`)
2. To throw away the last digit of a number, simply divide it by 10.
3. When finding digits that way, they will of course be returned in reverse order (least significant digit first) so you have to reverse the digits to get the correct answer. One way to do this is to store from the end to the beginning of a char array.
4. Negative numbers have to be handled specially. The easiest way is to note that the number is negative so that a `-` sign can be added when appropriate; then, negate the number to make it positive. However, note that you can't negate `int.MinValue`, so that has to be handled specially.
5. You can convert from a numeric digit to its `char` equivalent by adding it to the char `'0'` and casting the result back to `char`.

Here's an approach that uses those points:

```
public static string MyToString(int number)
{
    if (number == int.MinValue)
        return "-2147483648"; // Special case.

    char[] digits = new char[64]; // Support at most 64 digits.
    int last = digits.Length;
    bool isNegative = number < 0;

    if (isNegative)
        number = -number;

    do
    {
        digits[--last] = (char) ('0' + number % 10);
        number /= 10;
    }
    while (number != 0);

    if (isNegative)
        digits[--last] = '-';

    return new string(digits, last, digits.Length-last);
}
```

I think the main part you were asking about is how to get the digits of a number one-by-one, which is answered by the `do/while` loop above.

---

[EDIT] Addressed the points raised in the comments below.

Comment: Not bad, but fails for `int.MinValue` (in rather amusing fashion -- `"0123456789"[number % 10]` fails more obviously). Also, you could store the digits in reverse immediately and take the end of the string, rather than the beginning, though I agree that's not central to the exercise.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Ah yes, you can't negate int.MinValue. I guess if that was required then you could handle it specially. Good idea about storing the digits from the end. I'll update to do that.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Thank you very much Matthew! My problem was, that I did not understand how I could address the last digit of a number (numbers one-by-one == digits one-by-one, my bad..)

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you're not allowed to use any libraries. But if you need to do the conversion entirely by hand, you could do it something like this

```
private static string IntToString(int i)
{
    string[] digits = {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"};
    string sign = (i < 0 ? "-" : "");
    var absI = (i < 0 ? -i : i);
    string result = "";
    while (absI != 0)
    {
        int digit = absI % 10;
        result = digits[digit] + result;
        absI = (absI - digit) / 10;
    }
    return sign + result;
}
```

The code above doesn't work properly for zero. If you need that, it's very simple to add.

Answer (score 1):

For example you can split your number into individual characters:

```
// Note that this is just for example and for positive numbers only.
IEnumerable<char> ToChar(int num)
{
    while (num > 0)
    {
        // adding '0' to number will return char for that number
        char ch = (char)(num % 10 + '0');
        num /= 10;
        yield return ch;
    }
}
```

then create new string based on that:

```
string ToString(int num)
{
    // ToChar will return char collection in reverse order,
    // so you will need to reverse collection before using.
    // Well in your situation you will be probably needed to
    // to write Reverse method by yourself, so this is just for
    // working example
    var chArray = ToChar(num).Reverse().ToArray();
    string str = new string(chArray);
    return str;
}
```

and usage:

```
int i = 554;
string str = ToString(i);
```

References: [DotNetFiddle Example (with simplified ToChar() method)](https://dotnetfiddle.net/y9ICjy)

Comment: I'd disqualify this solution on technical grounds. Even if we allow iterators and `IEnumerable<T>` as part of the language, `Enumerable.Reverse()` and `Enumerable.ToArray()` are library calls (living in `System.Linq`). Otherwise, there's a lot more LINQ shenanigans we could pull (`.Range`, `.Select`, `.Join`).

Comment: @JeroenMostert This is not a solution to copy and paste in first place, it's kind of working "help" or "guide" to OP's question.